# Оптимизация оператора echo

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Такой вот странноватый вопрос у меня возник. Что оптимальней с точки зрения ресурсов сервера, браузера и протокола HTTP - использовать несколько раз оператор `echo` или собирать html-код в переменную, а затем выбрасывать ее в браузер? Например:

```
$html = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++) {
   $html .= "<p> $i - <img src='images/image_$i.png' /></p>";
}
echo $html;
```

или

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++) {
   echo "<p> $i - <img src='images/image_$i.png' /></p>";
}
```

Comment: из логических побуждений - конкатенация строк в цикле - более тяжелая операция, чем непосредственный вывод. 

По пробовали ли Вы провести тесты? узнали, что это узкое место? может Вашим узким местом является wifi пользователя или сам php.

Comment: О нет, мы снова пришли к этому вопросу. Реально оптимальней кэшировать шаблоны, а любимый срач echo vs print всегда возникает тогда, когда в коде есть гораздо более неоптимизированные штуки.  
Если вас очень-очень сильно это беспокоит, то можно провести сравнение, используя огромный предел $i и замеряя память (функцию не подскажу, но она есть) и прошедшее время (microtime(true)). Правда забавный нюанс будет в том, что с реально большим пределом на практике сталкиваться не придется, а с небольшим будет сильный разброс.

Comment: > Что оптимальней с точки зрения ресурсов сервера, браузера и протокола http

Ответ отдается браузеру **один** раз целиком. Пока скрипт не завершил работу, браузер ничего не получит.

Comment: Если буферизация вывода отключена, то первый вариант быстрее будет, а в обычном случае второй. Но если вам  хочется по какой-то причине вывести  все в $html  (например эта переменная используется где-то еще) то можно сделать через функции ob_start() и тд. но здесь этого не надо.

Comment: Если ваша задача — ускорить медленную выдачу страницы, подозреваю, что замена `echo` на конкатенацию никогда не будет решением. Займитесь реальными оптимизациями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев:*

[Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki): Ответ отдается браузеру один раз целиком. Пока скрипт не завершил работу, браузер ничего не получит. Поэтому с точки зрения протокола HTTP оба варианта эквивалентны.

[zb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11304/zb): Однако, с точки зрения сервера, если буферизация вывода отключена, то первый вариант быстрее будет, а в обычном случае - второй. Но если вам хочется по какой-то причине вывести все в `$html` (например эта переменная используется где-то еще) то можно сделать через буферизацию вывода при помощи ob-функций (ob_start() и т.д.).